# Call Method in Submit Button (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methods

When  i click Submit Button doing nothing, says not defined BorcEkle which one is called in HTML. 
I am using for guide another MVC Web App, they called like this, and it works.

**BorcEkle.cshtml**
**Submit Button and JS**

```js
function BorcEkle() {
        if ($("#aciklama").val() == null || $("#hesap").val() == null || $("#tutar").val() == null || $("#start").val() == null || $("#end").val() == null || $("#e12").val() == null) {
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Ups!',
                text: 'Lütfen alanları doldurunuz.',
                type: 'error',
                icon: 'ti ti-close',
                styling: 'fontawesome'
            });
        } else {
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Borç Eklendi',
                text: 'Borç verisi başarılyla eklendi.',
                type: 'success',
                icon: 'ti ti-check',
                styling: 'fontawesome'
            });

            $.post("@Url.Action("BorcEkle", "Dashboard")", {
                aciklama: $("#aciklama").val(),
                hesap: $("#hesap").val(),
                tutar: $("#tutar").val(),
                start: $("#start").val(),
                end: $("#end").val(),
                kategori: $("#e12").val()
            }, function(data) {
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Borç Eklendi',
                    text: 'Borç verisi başarılyla eklendi.',
                    type: 'success',
                    icon: 'ti ti-check',
                    styling: 'fontawesome'
                }).then(function() {
                    location.reload();

                }, function(dismis) {
                    if (dismis == 'cancel' || dismis == 'overlay') {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    }
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn" method="post" onclick="BorcEkle()">Kaydet</button>
```

**DashboardController.cs**

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BorcEkle(string aciklama, string hesap, decimal tutar, DateTime start, DateTime end , string kategori)
    {
        var addDebt = new TBLADDDEBT();
        addDebt.EXPLANATION = aciklama;
        addDebt.BILLACCUNT = hesap;
        addDebt.AMOUNT = tutar;
        addDebt.DATEOFISSUE = start;
        addDebt.DUEDATE = end;
        addDebt.TBLCATEGORY.CATEGORYNAME = kategori;
        addDebt.CATEGORYID = addDebt.TBLCATEGORY.CATEGORYID;
        addDebt.ISACTIVE = true;
        addDebt.REGDATE = DateTime.Now;
        addDebt.USERID = SessionModel.Current.User.USERID;
        //addDebt.EXPLANATION = form["Aciklama"].Trim();
        //addDebt.BILLACCUNT = form["Hesap"].Trim();
        //addDebt.AMOUNT = Convert.ToDecimal(form["Hesap"].Trim());
        //addDebt.DATEOFISSUE = Convert.ToDateTime(form["daterangepicker_start"]);
        //addDebt.DUEDATE = Convert.ToDateTime(form["daterangepicker_end"]);
        //addDebt.TBLCATEGORY.CATEGORYNAME = form["Kategori"]; 

        db.TBLADDDEBT.Add(addDebt);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: When i am trying something, I realized my daterangepicker1 data was wrong, how can got start date and end date in daterangepicker?

Comment: Open your browser console and see what is happening. Check the network tab to see whether it is making the ajax call. What is the response coming back

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).then is not a function(anonymous function) @ BorcEkle:546
That line :     }).then(function() {
                    location.reload();

Comment: Looks like you are calling `then` on `new  PNotify`. I do not know whether your PNotify returns a promise. I assume you intent to call this on the the `$.post` call

Comment: Ok, I delete `new PNotify` now its works, but i can't reach `DashboardController`'s `BorcEkle(.....)` function, how can reach with Submit button.
Actually i am trying this, i have a `form-groups`, i will get datas for database. But I couldn't.
**Thank you for quick response.**